# What is .self after a class name used for? Swift 3

Tags: swift, class, self

I recently noticed that some codes do init of instances like ClassName.self() for example:

```
let realm = try! Realm.self()
```

From the output and the usage thereafter, it is just like as though without it - Realm()

Is there any specific reason or usage for doing an init with .self?

Comment: Do you have a reference where `self()` is used like that? On https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ I can see only `let realm = try! Realm()` – and it should make no difference.

Comment: @MartinR It is actually from codes passed on to me, like I mentioned in the question, usage after such a declaration is as normal, e.g. try! realmUpdate.write so I could not understand why is there a need for the .self during the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat speculation, but I believe the places that *do* use `Type.self()` in the context of Realm follows a misperceived convention that has followed (some irrelevantly) the effects of Swift team resolving the bug

- [SR-899: `.self` can be omitted if a function has only one parameter](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-899)

The following commit by the Realm team was in preparation for the anticipated resolution of the bug above:

- [#3712 - explicitly use '`Type.self`' notation when passing types to Realm Swift APIs](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3712/files)

It's possible that the changes in the commit above (`Type` updated to `Type.self`, in proper context) has inspired code bases that make use of Realm to also make use of `Type.self` in initializer context, i.e., `Type.self()`. This is, however, a redundant use of the `.self` suffix.

Comment: So it is just like adding self when using the class owned parameters - e.g. self.frame. Not wrong but does not do anything?

Comment: @BenOng In that context, sometimes we're required to use the `self` suffix, e.g. to help the compiler differentiate between class owned parameters and same-named local parameters (commonly used in e.g. initializer, `self.foo = foo`). But yes, the use of `self` in the context you describe is redundant, and I see no reason for it; a similar case would be using e.g. `Realm.init()` rather than `Realm()` (the `.init` does have its uses, but is also only redundant, in some cases).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! I'll accept this until I find another reason for the use of .self

Comment: @BenOng Happy to help.